# LM2576 vs modern step-down switching regulators - EMC requirements and other differences

Tags: voltage-regulator, emc, switching-regulator

I'm looking for some cost reduction in my design and I want to replace TPS54302 with LM2576 or LM2575.

In my case - switching regulator works as a pre-regulator with 12-24V input and ~6V output, followed by 3.3V 200mA linear regulator and 5.0V 1A LDO. Additionally circuit with about 30 LEDs (15mA each) is powered directly from pre-regulator.

TPS54203 features (from [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps54302.pdf?ts=1616523195241&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)):

[image]

LM2576 features (from [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2576.pdf?ts=1616474852127&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)):

[image]

So the main difference (regarding EMI) is that TPS54203 has frequency spread feature, which "reduces EMI" (or more correctly - spreads EMI over some frequency range).

Another difference is that TPS54203 works near 400kHz and LM2576 works at fixed 52kHz.

And third main difference is efficiency I guess. I don't worry about this, device is not battery-powered and there will be no problem with heat disspation.

Questions:

1. Shall I worry about EMI/EMC when I replace TPS54302 with LM2576?
2. Is there something else (besides EMI) that should I worry about when I replace TPS54302 with LM2576?

Comment: The inductor will be much bigger and heavier with the LM2576. You might want to widen the field a bit, there are many other possibilities.